# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. C# when using Memory stream

Tags: c#, large-data, memorystream

I am working with wpf application and memory stream write method is used in that to write dicom data bytes.It shows the Exception of type `System.OutOfMemoryException` when try to write big dicom data having size more than 70 mb. Can you please suggest any solution to resolve this.

The piece of code is like this

```
try
            {
                using ( MemoryStream imagememoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        // Retrieve the DICOMData.
                        // data comes as chunks; if file size is larger, multiple RetrieveDICOMData() calls
                        // has to be raised. the return value specifies whether the chunk is last one or not.                  
                        dicomData = dicomService.RetrieveDICOMData( hierarchyInfo );
                        imagememoryStream.Write( dicomData.DataBytes, 0, dicomData.DataBytes.Length );
                        if (dicomData.IsLastChunk)
                        {
                            // data is smaller; completed reading so, end
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    imageData=imagememoryStream.ToArray();
                }
                return imageData;
            }
            catch( Exception exception )
            {
                throw new DataException( exception.StackTrace );
            }
```

Comment: Can you not write this data in chunks? Why must it be so large?

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: *I say sir, it does seem like your process is ... out of memory. Quite peculiar indeed!* said no programmer who understood how much address space is accessible to a 32-bit process, ever.

Comment: Try to call GC.Collect(); inside the loop.

Comment: I have used GC.Collect() inside the loop , but same issue happens... Any alternates??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153702/system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown-when-there-is-still-plenty-of-memory-fr

Answer (score 3):

It is quite common for MemoryStream to throw OutOfMemoryExceptions due to lack of contiguous (not total) memory available. There are a number of alternate implementations that lessen this problem. Take a look at [MemoryTributary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348590/A-replacement-for-MemoryStream) for example.

Or, depending on your needs, you could try writing direct to storage instead of memory.

Comment: It is working fine.Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion. But I have a dependancy project in managed cpp, it shows "Not enough storage to process this command" exception. Can you suggest any solution.