# Uploading .xlsx file using NPOI in C# throws SystemMemoryOutOfException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, npoi

I need to basically import .xlsx file using NPOI in c#. Following is the code that I have written.

```
XSSFWorkbook xssfwb;
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(excelPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  xssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
}
```

I am getting SystemOutOfMemory exception at the line of code  xssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
Can ane tell the reason why this is happening ?

Comment: What's the file size? Is it too large. Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153702/system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown-when-there-is-still-plenty-of-memory-fr

Comment: The filesize is 10 mb and the number of rows are 213140. I think the link that you have shared is got to do with some other problem.

Comment: I tried with a smaller size file and it worked. How to handle larger files

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you solve that?