# Import large XML file into SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-ce

I try to import data from a XML file into SQL Server CE database. I use ErikEJ SQL Server Compact Bulk Insert Library (from NuGet) [this library on codeplex](https://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/). I create database and table. Then I read XML to `DataTable` and import this `DataTable` to DB table.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("myxml.xml");
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table = ds.Tables[0];
String connString = @"Data Source = test.sdf";
SqlCeBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlCeBulkCopy(connString);
bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "testtable";
bulkInsert.WriteToServer(table);
```

It works on a small xml, but when I use large xml (more then 1gb) I get this error on `ReadXml` :

> "System.OutOfMemoryException" in mscorlib.dll

How to fix this?

update: I know that this error because I use large xml - question is how optimize this algorithm, mayby using buffer or read xml part by part, any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown when there is still plenty of memory free](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153702/system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown-when-there-is-still-plenty-of-memory-fr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple libary that will solve this for you.

You need to read the XML file in a streaming fashion ( [Reading Xml with XmlReader in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp) ) to avoid loading the entire XML file, and then for each element read add these to  a List or DataTable, up to say 100,000 entries, then BulkInsert those, dispose/clear all unused objects and go on, until the entire file has been read.

In addition, calls to SqlCeBulkCopy should be wrapped in usings to dispose unmanaged resources:

```
using (SqlCeBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlCeBulkCopy(connString))
{
   bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "testtable";
   bulkInsert.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

Comment: Thk, but if I use `DataTable.ReadXml()` how to limit for examle 100000 entries? And then begin from 100001?

Comment: Dont use DataTable.ReadXml, but use a xmlreader and add 1 row per read to a DataTable or List<T>, and count how many you have added. When you reach 100000, then run blukcopy, and continue...