# Where to set <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>?

Tags: c#, arrays, mono

I'm working on a little program on sorting lists. Now, I need an array that requires more than 2GB of RAM. During my research, I found the  property, but I don't know where so set it. I'm using Mono.

Comment: P.S: I mean the property <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>

Answer (score 20):

> For very large ArrayList objects, you can increase the maximum capacity to 2 billion elements on a 64-bit system by setting the enabled attribute of the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects configuration element to true in the run-time environment.

#### MyCustomApp.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

#### Usage:

```
mono64 --config MyCustomApp.config Foobar.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using appsettings.json you can use it like this:

```
    "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcAllowVeryLargeObjects": {
      "enabled": true
      }
    }
```