# TFS 2017.2 - Build The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ExtensionManagement.WebApi.ExtensionUtil' threw an exception

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

After upgrading TFS2017 to update 2, every build fails instantly with the above error. I've tried running the build agent from a console window but it looks like the jobs never hit it as it just stays at "listening for jobs". I've tried click 'download all logs as zip' but the zip archive appears empty! Are there any other logs or additional verbose logging to be enabled?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did your agent run in interactive mode or as a service ?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT In event viewer on the server I can see the error - TF400703: Unable to initialize the specified service Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ExtensionManagement.Sdk.Server.InstalledExtensionFallbackService. with the inner exception : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. (type OutOfMemoryException) but the server is using 12GB out of 16GB so memory should be ok

Comment: "“Out Of Memory” Does Not Refer to Physical Memory, about this error please take a look at Fredrik Mörk's answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153702/system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown-when-there-is-still-plenty-of-memory-fr  Moreover, the error is related to extensionmanagement, have you installed any extension on your TFS server, try to uninstall it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reconfigure the build agent first. Open a command prompt in **admin** mode and navigate to the folder where the build agent is located and the there is a  **`ConfigureAgent.cmd`**  exist. Re-run the `ConfigureAgent.cmd` and  "Do you want to also replace the server registration (default is N)" Choose "**Y**".

For other logs you could also check the **Event View** on your build agent server if there are some useful info.