# ASP.NET Core + PostgreSQL - 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. How can I fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

I'm creating an application in ASP.NET Core. And now I want to install my app in Linux using nginx, PostgreSQL. I'm uploaded my project to Linux and it work's. But I can't connect to DataBase. I'm using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL plugin for working with PostgreSQL.

When I run my application I'm getting the following exception:

> **An error occurred while seeding the database. System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
> 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.**

The PostgreSQL in Linux is installed and I created the database. But what's problem?

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know C# but the answers to this question might help: ['System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown when there is still plenty of memory free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153702/system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown-when-there-is-still-plenty-of-memory-fr). Have you tried adding more RAM?

Comment: The database is empty. I don't think I need a large storage size.